# Where does the Advanced Filter Control for Visual Studio LightSwitch store saved filters?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Just spent a lot of time searching for answers to problems surrounding the filter put out by microsoft for Lightswitch.

After solving problems with an error that appears for a lot of people, it still does not save the filter.  The filter seems to save without error.  The filter names appear in the dropdown, but when I open and close the app, they are all gone.

I was wondering if it is becasue I do not have a local database but only a remote sql server database.

Here is the control I am talking about:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Filter-Control-for-Visual-90fb8e93

At first it was throwing the following error on save but I got past that by making a method public.

```
error in FilterControl:            the data contract type      "lightswitchfilter.Client.FilterControls.Clause" cannot be serialized because the member "_clauseType" is not public.
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lsextensibility/thread/322b0220-04a4-4c2d-bc7d-5fee9b14ab2f

Answer (score 0):

IT gets stored in Isolated Storage